# HIVE: CREATE TABLE AS SELECT command cannot specify the list of columns for the target table

Tags: hadoop, hive

How can I make this work?

```
  hive> desc temp;
  OK
  a                     int                                         
  b                     int                                         
  Time taken: 0.077 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

I want to create t2 HIVE table with column names c and d but getting below error.

```
  hive> create table t2(c int,d int) as select a,b from temp;
  FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10065]: CREATE TABLE AS SELECT command         cannot specify the list of columns for the target table
```

Answer (score 5):

You need not to mention table schema again as you are specifying to take the schema from another table. So your table creation statement should be like

```
create table t2 as select a,b from temp;
```

Comment: but I want column name to change for t2. Also I do not want to do like: create table t2 as select a c,b c from temp;

Comment: You can not do like that. After creating the table you can change the column names using the alter statement.

ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE [COLUMN] col_old_name col_new_name column_type [COMMENT col_comment] [FIRST|AFTER column_name]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but by definition, but in case anyone else has the same question, the answer is pretty straightforward.

By definition, `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` is used to persist a resultset as a table. This means that if you want the new table to have different column names, you need to use a different resultset to create it. An easy way you do that is with column aliases:

```
create table t2 as select a as c, b as d from temp;
```

I know you said you didn't want to do this (although there was a small typo - your query would fail because it would try to name both columns c), but hopefully this explains why you should approach it this way: you need to build a dataset whose metadata matches the table you want to create.